# Firebase Phone Authentication not functioning for Release variant - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play

I have gone through numerous questions on SO about this issue but I am unable to figure out what my issue is. I have take the following steps:

1. Created a key/keystore in Android Studio
2. Signed the aab file with the key
3. Upload the app to Play Store - opted in for app signing
4. Retrieved the generated SHA-1 and SHA-256 values and pasted them in Firebase console
5. Verified the values through `signingReport` in Android Studio

I've also added `signingConfigs` into my gradle build file. I confirmed that the keys in Firebase are for the release build.

Everything seems to be in order but I am not able to get into the OTP screen for the Phone Auth. Its been mightily frustrating. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apart from updating the SHA-1 fingerprints in Firebase, you might have to update it in your Google Cloud API settings as well. This should apply in the event you have created restricted API keys. Just add the additional keys with the same package names and it should work.

I spent the good part of 1 day figuring this out.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? I´m struggling with making firebase Auth works in release variant, I don´t find where can I add the figerprint in Google Cloud